# Filter and map issue with API

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm using the OpenWeather API 5 day 3 hour forecast and my response JSON is giving me 40 items in an array. I am filtering the array so I can get a daily temperature (15:00:00) and then using map to render each item. But that leaves me with an array of 5 items when I need the 40 items to render the 3 hour forecast in backside of the same component.

The idea is to render the daily temperature on the front-face of the card and a 3 hour forecast on the back of the card with my flip CSS function. So when you press the card it will flip to the backside and render the 3 hourly forecast.

How can I render the daily temperature and still render the 3 hourly forecast in the same component when i am filtering the array to 5 items?

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

```
fetch(
  "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=" +
    this.state.userInput +
    "&units=metric&APPID="
)
  .then(results => {
    return results.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    let days = data.list.filter(day => {
        return day.dt_txt.endsWith("15:00:00");
      })
      .map((day, index) => {
        return (
          <CardComponent
            i={index}
            flip={e => {
              let card = document.getElementById(index);
              card.classList.toggle("is-flipped");
            }}
            date={day.dt_txt.slice(5, 11)}
            temp={Math.round(day.main.temp)}
          />
        );
      });
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        days: days,
        userInput: ""
      };
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {});
```

};

Comment: Don't filter the data immediately. Pass a whole day to a component as props and determine what to render within that component based on user interaction

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend moving your component out of your fetch call, and instead using setState:

```
state = { days: [] }

let days = data.list.filter(day => {
  return day.dt_txt.endsWith("15:00:00");
})

this.setState({ days })
```

Then in your render:

```
<div>
  {this.state.days.length > 0 ?
    this.state.days.map(d => <CardComponent data={d} />) :
    <div>Loading...</div>
  }
</div>
```

This way you can render a loading message, then populate your component once you have data. This way you can assume within your `CardComponent` component that you have all the data you will need for the front and back states.

It will also make your loading and error states a lot easier to handle.

**EDIT:**

To loop through the dates and create arrays of forecasts for each of the five days, I've created a very rough example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/n1wpjoy1l0

I've used a `for` loop to iterate 5 times, and increment by 1 day, creating a filtered array each time for days that match the current day.

Comment: What I forgot to add to my above code is that the fetch call is in my handleFormSubmit. So everytime the user inputs a city in the inputfield the fetch runs. Maping in my render could be a problem then?

Comment: That's okay - it doesn't change the fact that your fetch call should complete and then setState, and your component should pick up the data and act accordingly. You don't need to use a loading or error state, but it's generally recommended for data coming from a network call.

Comment: Just saw your comment edit - no, not a problem. I would declare state as in my answer - `state = { days: [] }` then update with your real array of data in the fetch call.

Comment: Hmm not quite sure I follow here sorry. I'm still mapping over the filtered array which still gives me 5 items when I need access to the 40 items after my filter

Comment: I've added a code sandbox example to my answer. The good news is that the code is fairly succinct, the bad news is that I had to add a date library (date-fns) in order to loop through the days. This might work for your needs, it might not - but take a look and see if you can use this.